# Video streaming from the server side to the client side

Tags: video, video-streaming, vlcj

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Video Streaming in vlcj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343523/video-streaming-in-vlcj)

```
public class VlcTest extends VlcjTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if(args.length != 1) {
      System.out.println("Specify a single MRL to stream");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
    Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);

    String media = args[0];
    String [] options = formatHttpStream("127.0.0.1", 5080);

    System.out.println("Streaming '" + media + "' to '" + options + "'");

    MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory(args);
    HeadlessMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newHeadlessMediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.playMedia(media, options);
    // Don't exit
    Thread.currentThread().join();
  }

  private static String [] formatHttpStream(String serverAddress, int serverPort) {
    String [] sb={":sout = #duplicate{dst=std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=127.0.0.1:5080}}"};
    return sb;
  }
}
```

I want to confirm that can this code is able to stream the video from the server to the client side. The flow I am trying to achieve is:

1. Client sends request to server for stream
2. Server creates connection to client to send the video in packets based on the clients ip address and port number.

Comment: Didn't you ask this same question yesterday? [Video Streaming in vlcj](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343523/video-streaming-in-vlcj)

Answer (score 0):

No this code will not do what you want all. Please refer to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11347526/3340) on your previous question for why. Especially the section **"Explanation of StreamHttp.java part"**.